# For my Java applet, will I need differently-sized graphics for each screen size?

Tags: java, graphics

I am a beginner at programming Java applets.  I'm currently designing a website for desktop/mobile screens.  I would like the applet to show up on as many different devices as possible (for example, desktop, tablets, and iPads).

One question I have is about incorporating graphics into a Java applet.  I guess I'm over-thinking it, but I'd like to know if the graphics will resize if the Java applet resizes.  Will I need differently-sized graphics for each individual screen size?

Comment: *" Will I need differently-sized graphics for each individual screen size?"*  That depends how the applet is written, but I am pretty sure many of the smaller devices do not run Java at all. Perhaps look to HTML 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your main question here:

> if the graphics will resize if the Java applet resizes.

For the full explanation, I will say when you initialize applet. As you said, every device has its own size, so you should take size of applet base on size of device.

And, when user resize the applet, the applet will **automatically** call method `repaint`, and every your graphics will repaint again, great !!!

But, it doesn't mean your graphics will resize. it depends on how you write your graphics code in applet. if size of graphics base on width/height of applet, it will resize base on formula you has set. but if you make size of graphics base on constant number, nothing happen. it will repaint the graphics, but with **same size**.

Hope this help :)